# Place anchor button next to label (and treat as part of label)

Tags: jquery-mobile

Using jQuery mobile, I'm trying to place a "search" button just to the right of a field label and so that the button is treated as part of the label when the window is sized/resized.

The code below results in the button moving with the label but it is always displayed below the label instead of to the right of the label (even when there is plenty of room for the button).

```
<label for="FOO">Foo<a data-role="button" data-icon="search" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" href="#FooSearch"> </a></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you always want it to the right, surround it with a div set for nowrap:

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap">
```

otherwise try

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
```

Answer (score 0):

Doh! It turns out I actually had a div around the anchor, which, when removed seems to have eliminated the issue.  So the code as I showed it here actually does work.  Thanks for the suggestion ezanker. It made me look closer at what I really had.